# Custom calendar view for Office 365 outlook calendar

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office365-apps, outlook-web-app

Is it possible to create custom calendar view for Office365 calendar?
[image]

Comment: Have you made any progress as I would like to do same for Outlook 2010

Comment: No, It is not possible to build in custom view into Outlook. I create separate app that use Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Do you know if the Microsoft Graph API is available for Sharepoint 2010? Did you completely design the calendar from scratch or could you use any "Microsoft calendar design template"? Did you create any plug in for Outlook Client to reflect the same information there?